# Move parent div and keep child at same position

Tags: html, css

I want to move the parent div via transition in x-direction, but the child element is supposed to stay at its position. The parent div is also rotated and affects the child div position. How can I achieve the child div to stand still?

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ksepejm/5/)

HTML

```
<div><span>Hello</span>
```

SCSS

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(13deg) ;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s;

  span {
   display: block;
   transform:  rotate(-13deg); 
   transition: all 1s;
  }

&.move {
   transform: translate(200px,0) rotate(13deg);

   span {
    transform: translate(-200px,0) rotate(-13deg) ; 
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 &.move {
   transform: translate(200px) rotate(13deg) ;
   span {
   transform: translate(0) rotate(-13deg) ; 
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: the text shall stay at its initial position

Answer (score 1):

Changing `translate` position of your `span` element will help you achieve what you're seeking as:

### Code Snippet

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('div').toggleClass('move');
})
```

```css
div {
  margin: 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(13deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s;
}
div span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  transform: rotate(-13deg);
  transition: all 1s;
}
div.move {
  transform: translate(200px) rotate(13deg);
}
div.move span {
  transform: translate(-190px, 44px) rotate(-13deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div>
  <span>hallo</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a really wise method since you would have to adjust that manually and lose a lot of time for each animation to get the position fit